# Creating Java objects from SQL DDL statements

Tags: java, sql, parsing, sybase

I am looking for some existing library in java which is capable of parsing a `SQL DDL` statements, which is capable of doing this:

Say I have a table as follows :

```
create table emp
(
  name varchar(20),
  empid int,
  date_of_joining date
);
```

Then, I want a class with the following constructor:

```
Emp(String name, int empid, Date date_of_joining)
```

Now, if we someone changes the schema of the table as follows:

```
alter table emp 
add salary double;

Emp(String name, int empid, Date date_of_joining, double salary)

alter table emp 
modify empid varchar(6);

Emp(String name, String empid, Date date_of_joining, double salary)
```

Is there something already existing, which does something lie this ?

Comment: Those are ORM libraries like Hibernate, TopLink and DataNucleus.

Comment: what he said. Java is statically typed.

Comment: Duplicate as well of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794777/how-to-create-a-class-dynamically-in-java

Comment: I have never used Hibernate, but from what I am guessing they are based on `xml' files. At least, That's how they do it in my company's ORM. But I don't want to read fem a xml file, but from a sql file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Hibernate Tools Reverse Engineering.

It doesn't parse raw SQL files, but can connect to a SQL database, and generate Java POJOs from your schema.

http://docs.jboss.org/tools/4.1.0.Final/en/hibernatetools/html_single/index.html#refeng_codegen

It won't make parameterized constructors for you out-of-the-box, but you could customize its templates, or use Lombok:

http://projectlombok.org/features/Constructor.html

Frankly, I'd go the **other** way. Update the database schema from Java POJOs. Why? Database Table Inheritance. It's easy to declare using JPA, but there's no common pattern for declarative table inheritance in SQL.